# Shader compiling crashes if android layout is used

Tags: android, opengl-es, shader

Shader compilation fails if I want to use any native interface above my SurfaceView.

If I start application like this everything is ok:

```
surfaceView = new mSurfaceView(this);
renderer = new mRender();
surfaceView.setRenderer(renderer);
setContentView(surfaceView);
```

but if I want to use any interface it fails. I'm applying layout like this:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
surfaceView = (mSurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.gl_surface_view);
renderer = new mRender();
surfaceView.setRenderer(renderer);
```

App crashes on compiling shaders. This is my code:

```
protected int compileShader(int shaderType, String shaderCode)
{
    int shaderHandle = GLES20.glCreateShader(shaderType);

    if (shaderHandle != 0)
    {
        // Pass in the shader source.
        GLES20.glShaderSource(shaderHandle, shaderCode);

        // Compile the shader.
        GLES20.glCompileShader(shaderHandle);

        // Get the compilation status.
        final int[] compileStatus = new int[1];
        GLES20.glGetShaderiv(shaderHandle, GLES20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS, compileStatus, 0);

        // If the compilation failed, delete the shader.
        if (compileStatus[0] == 0)
        {
            GLES20.glDeleteShader(shaderHandle);
            shaderHandle = 0;
        }
    }

    if (shaderHandle == 0)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error creating shader.");
    }

    return shaderHandle;
}
```

Shader is not compiled successfully so shaderHandle is 0 and app crashes on this line:

```
throw new RuntimeException("Error creating shader.");
```

It compiles fine without layout. I think that the problem is that in first variant I'm creating layout this way: surfaceView = new mSurfaceView(this); but in crashing variant I create it this way: surfaceView = (mSurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.gl_surface_view); I think it crashes because of it but I don't know why. It looks fine for me and I don't see the problem.

This is how surface view looks in main.xml:

```
<engine.core.mSurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/gl_surface_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: What's the error message returned by GLES20.glGetShaderInfoLog?

Comment: Sounds like you might be trying to compile shaders before you have a valid context. At what point in the activity lifecycle are you building these shaders?

Comment: haffax, it returns an empty string

Comment: Tim, I'm building shaders in onSurfaceCreated method. By that time I've already loaded several models from raw resources and I need context to do that. So seems like context is valid.